# Determine latest/end/max offset for all partitions of a topic

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Via the `Processor` API only the current offset and partition can be retrieved, but I haven't found a way to determine the latest/end/max offset for all partitions of a topic. Is there a way to do this?